# Switching from Gazebo to a "real" robot

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, urdf, spawn

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

so far i have been using gazebo to simulate my algorithms (and then simulating the results in Gazebo), but now i have a real robot available and i wanted to know how i can load the urdf model (so i can see it in "rviz" and profit of the links to "tf ") without using the spawn robot launch file:

```
<node name="robot_spawner" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="$(optenv ROBOT_INITIAL_POSE) -unpause -urdf -param robot_description -model mobile_base"/>
```

of gazebo_ros (because this launch script also launches gazebo).

Any suggestion would be very appreciated

Marcus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196415/switching-from-gazebo-to-a-%22real%22-robot/) by [Marcus](https://answers.ros.org/users/11016/marcus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2014-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That launch command assumes that the urdf has been written to the parameter robot_description. In Rviz, add a RobotModel to the displays with the topic robot_description (should be the default).

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus](https://answers.ros.org/users/11016/marcus/) on 2014-11-02**:
Thanks David, that worked perfectly.